# Export selection to a new file in WebStorm 10?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In my `app.js` file I have this code :

```
myApp.directive("inventoryProduct", function ()
{
    return {

        restrict: "E",
        scope   : {
            name : "@",
            price: "@",
            onReport:"&"
        },
        template: "<div><b>{{name}} costs {{ price}}$</b></div>\n<div>\n    <button class=\"btn btn-lg btn-danger\" ng-click=\"onReport({IDontKnowA:name,IDontKnowB:price})\">Change name</button>\n</div>"

    }
})
```

Looking at the `template`'s value  , It is a HTML string.

**Question**

Assuming I'm selecting the html string / any string —

Is there any option in Webstorm to : *"Move selection to a new file"* and having this new file name so that now the file will be :

```
myApp.directive("inventoryProduct", function ()
{
    return {

        restrict: "E",
        scope   : {
            name : "@",
            price: "@",
            onReport:"&"
        },
        template: "newFile.js"  

    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no such refactorings. Please feel free to create a request for this feature in youtrack. Related ticket: [WEB-1232](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1232)

Comment: The guy opened a ticket in 2011. Now with angular templating , the guys in jetbrains should put more effort to it. I'm just saying.